# How visualize shinyapp which is dockerized?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have tried to make a docker image for my shiny app and push it into docker hub. All the steps look run well but I do not know why I cannot see the app?

steps that i run:

Step 1: docker file.

```
# get shiny packages image
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

#system libraries of general use
## install debian packages
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install libxml2-dev libcairo2-dev 
libsqlite3-dev libmariadbd-dev libpq-dev libssh2-1-dev unixodbc-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev

## update system libraries
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get clean

# install R packages required 
# (change it dependeing on the packages you need)
RUN R -e "install.packages(pkgs=c('shiny','ggplot2','data.table','DT','dplyr','tidyr','tibble','VennDiagram'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

# expose port
EXPOSE 3838

# run app on container start
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app.R', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838)"]
```

step 2:

```
docker build -t enhancer .
```

[image]

step 3:

```
docker run -p 8081:3838 --name enhancerexplorer -d enhancer
```

[image]

step 4:

```
docker tag enhancerexplorer sy/enhancerexplorer
```

step 5:

```
docker push sy/enhancerdata
```

[image]

but I cannot see the app using `localhost:8081`.

I also noticed that the status of image is `exited` and I have tried to active it using:
`docker start enhancerexplorer` but it didn`t work.

[image]

Comment: If it's status is `exited`, then that means that it ran and, well, exited. That in the brackets is the exit code, and `1` means something's not working properly in your shiny app. Have you tried `docker logs enhancerexplorer`, maybe something is logged there?

Comment: Thank you for reply.  I ran it and I found that it cannot find the app.R director. But I am working in the same path that app.R exist. "Loading required package: shiny
Error in normalizePath(appFile, mustWork = TRUE) :
  path[1]="/app.R": No such file or directory
Calls: <Anonymous> ... as.shiny.appobj.character -> shinyAppFile -> normalizePath
Execution halted".

Comment: I need to introduce COPY /app.R  /app.R in Dockerfile.